# How long is an incomplete UK visa saved on Gov.UK site

Tags: visas, uk

I started my application for a UK visa about 30 days ago, but will only be able to submit it in 3-4 weeks (missing some information at the moment). How long is my partially complete visa saved on the Gov.UK website?

Additionally, is there a way to delete the application I started? (so I can just start afresh when I have all the info)

Comment: Either 30 days, or 10 weeks is the best info I can find online.  All 2nd hand info tho.

Answer (score 2):

As per the UK GOV website:

> ##### When you cannot sign in
>
> You can only sign in if you’ve started a visa application and entered your email address.
>
> You may not be able to sign in if you’ve not returned to your application for over 10 weeks.